# Auth view files in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laravel 10 project:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This created User model, but nothing else.

Than I published:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-auth
```

Which outputs:

```
No publishable resources for tag
```

I don't see a view or route for authentication. What am I missing?

Comment: do you see it in tags when you try php artisan vendor:publish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 10, I solved by installing Breeze:

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

And than:

```
php artisan breeze:install blade
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the Laravel 10 doc about Authentication https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication and use a starter kit or Fortify

Comment: This could have been a comment